# Zip code checker error

Tags: php, zipcode

I am attempting to construct a postcode checker for a small number of stores in Australia. Basically, the customer enters their zip code and the site will then redirect to appropriate local pricing/services.

I am using [this](http://waww.com.au/ramblings/determine-state-from-postcode-in-australia) as a base but I am having a problem (listed by one of the comments on that site too) that no matter what value is entered for some reason the code marks the zip as SA even when it is completely different.

The code I am using is below.

```
<?php
// v1.0 Postcode Checker Just iStuff
// Copyright Ben Green 2014
// Redirect Customers to Appropriate Local Pricing and Services
// Sets cookie upon entering postcode, will then remember postcode for 3 days on customer's system

if (preg_match('#^\d+$#', $_POST['cf_postcode'])):

else:
    print "Please enter your postcode correctly.";
endif;

$postcode = $_POST['cf_postcode'];

function findState($postcode) {
    $ranges = array(
        'NSW' => array(
            1000, 1999,
            2000, 2599,
            2619, 2898,
            2921, 2999
        ),
        'ACT' => array(
            200, 299,
            2600, 2618,
            2900, 2920
        ),
        'VIC' => array(
            3000, 3999,
            8000, 8999
        ),
        'QLD' => array(
            4000, 4999,
            9000, 9999
        ),
        'SA' => array(
            5000, 5999
        ),
        'WA' => array(
            6000, 6797,
            6800, 6999
        ),
        'TAS' => array(
            7000, 7999
        ),
        'NT' => array(
            800, 999
        )
    );
    $exceptions = array(
        0800 => 'NT',
        872 => 'NT',
        2540 => 'NSW',
        2611 => 'ACT',
        2620 => 'NSW',
        3500 => 'VIC',
        3585 => 'VIC',
        3586 => 'VIC',
        3644 => 'VIC',
        3707 => 'VIC',
        2899 => 'NSW',
        6798 => 'WA',
        6799 => 'WA',
        7151 => 'TAS'
    );

    $postcode = intval($postcode);
    if ( array_key_exists($postcode, $exceptions) ) {
        return $exceptions[$postcode];
    }

    foreach ($ranges as $state => $range)
    {
        $c = count($range);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i+=2) {
            $min = $range[$i];
            $max = $range[$i+1];
            if ( $postcode >= $min && $postcode <= $max ) {
                return $state;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

//Redirect for NT
if ($state = NT)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/ntrepairs.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }

//Redirect for QLD  
if ($state = QLD)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/mailin.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }

//Redirect for VIC      
if ($state = VIC)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/mailin.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }

//Redirect for ACT
if ($state = ACT)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/mailin.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }

//Redirect for NSW
if ($state = NSW)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/mailin.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }

//Redirect for WA   
if ($state = WA)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/mailin.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }

//Redirect for TAS
if ($state = TAS)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/mailin.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }

//Redirect for SA       
if ($state = SA)
{
    header( "Location: http://www.justistuff.com.au/sarepairs.php" );
    setcookie("postcode", $postcode, time()+259200);

    }
```

I can't seem to work out what is causing it to redirect to SA even when the value entered (for example 2142) is clearly marked as NSW

Comment: Did you run this code with warnings enabled and e.g. check php log for messages. For example I have no idea what you mean on this line `if ($state = NT)` is NT defined somewhere??

Comment: Also make this so others can run it, where are you calling your function I can't see how I could even try this also consider simplifying your example. I don't know what the redirect has to do with you question ?!

Comment: I haven't run any debugging as of yet (still discovering the world of PHP), I thought that NT was defined further up when the code initially calculates the state based on the inputted postcode and then based on that choose whether it is SA, NT, WA, QLD etc. I must be wrong!

Comment: Hi Brandin, where would you suggest I post it so that others can run it? Thanks

Comment: Checking the log is not really debugging, it is how you check for errors in the script. Basically you should aim to remove all warning and notices. It doesn't look like it would run because i don't see where you call your function findState

Comment: That makes sense thanks for your help, so what would be easiest way to call upon the function so that I can redirect a user based on the state they are placed in by the zip code checker? (Sorry for all the questions I'm trying to get my head around it)

Comment: No I mean in your code you define function findState but you never call it. I think really you need to try to simplify the example maybe you're getting mixed up with different questions. For example the redirection thing is a different problem from classifying the zip code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($state = VIC)
```

That has two issues. First of all = is used for assignment, not for comparison. Secondly VIC is a string and should be in quotes like

```
if ($state == 'VIC')
```

Fix that for all your if statements and you're good.

**Also**, you are not calling findState function anywhere, before you start comparing the list of states you need to call that function to see what state your postcode belongs to

```
$state=findState($postcode);

//if($state=="thisthat")
```

Comment: I gave that a go, but now all that's happening is when I submit the zip code, it loads the file with the code above in it and loads a blank page, so it still isn't executing properly

Comment: After adding in the final piece (calling the function) the script now works like a charm, thank you so much for your patience and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

it is classic `==` problem, in your if you have assignment operator used instead of equality operator.

Also, I suggest using `exit` whenever you use `header redirect`, it ensure the next line of code didn't get executed.

To explain the problem from your partial code. you are using `if` statement to compare and then instead of equality you are assigning the value to $state. this result in `true` for if and hence the code instead `if` block will get executed. Since you don't have `exit` it parse next `if`.

I suggest changing your `if` to `switch` with `break` in there.